# Counterexample of 2nd geometric form of Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I recall the 2nd geometric form of Hahn-Banach theorem :

> Let $E$ be a real locally-convex topological vector space.
> Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty disjoint and convex subsets of $E$, $A$ being closed and $B$ being compact. Then there are a bounded linear form $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and two constants $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\varepsilon>0$ such that
> \begin{cases}
> \forall x\in A,\ f(x)\leq a-\varepsilon\\\forall y\in B,\ f(x) \geq a+\varepsilon
> \end{cases}

Is there a "simple" example of a non locally-convex topological vector space that provides a counterexample to this theorem ? The only example of a non locally-convex topological vector space i know comes from the metric space $(L^p([0,1]),d)$ for $0<p<1$ where the metric $d$ is defined as such

$$\forall g,h\in L^p([0,1]),\quad d(g,h)=\int_0^1 |g(t)-h(t)|^p\,dt$$

but its only convex subset is $L^p([0,1])$ itself, which can't provide such a counterexample.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Isn't a single point a convex subset of $L^p$?

Comment: Dumb of me to forget about the most simple examples. So you'd take two points and since the only continuous linear form over $L^{1/2}$ is the zero form, we can't separate them. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from mihaild)
Take two different points in $L^{1/2}$. Since the only continuous linear form over $L^{1/2}$ is $t\mapsto 0$, we can't separate these singletons.